# Mongodb - Default Index Creation - Background Construction

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing, spring-mongo

I am currently using `3.2.1 mongo driver version`.

**Use Case -**

**Write** - Bulk Insert in Collection or per row insert
**Read** - Read on basis of `_id`.

No extra indexes required, default index which mongodb creates on **_id** field is enough.

**Problem** - **My Mongo Service (calling mongodb) is taking too much of CPU load.**

1.) Does Mongodb creates indexes on **_id** field in background.

2.) If not do i need to make it create index in background to fasten the process. How can i do that programmatically.

Maybe something like this,

```
collection.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("_id", 1),new BasicDBObject("background", true));
```

I came across this [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/core/index-creation/#index-creation-background)

Comment: Check this https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.2/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html, no method for (BasicDBObject, IndexOptions)

Comment: There's an index by default on `_id` field, and you can't change it. By referring to your "Mongo Service", you mean your mongodb service, or your application?

Comment: @yaoxing application service, not mongo service. Yes index on `_id` is by default, but does it run in background, if not can i make it to build index in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running an index in the background does not make inserting run faster, on the contrary, it runs slower. However, the query will be asynchronous, thus allowing your application to run other queries in the mean time.

You can try the following approaches to improve the performance on bulk inserts

- Create a replica that allows reads on secondary nodes. This will have inserts running on the primary node while reads will be directed to the secondary. Running indexing in the background will help in this case. It is important to avoid reading stale data in this case.
- Create a new index that works well with the shape of data you are inserting.

  - Create several indexes using a variation of keys on the collection.
  - Run an insert query on a small data set. Mongo will analyze all the 
    indexes available on the collection and pick the one that performs the 
    best for the shape of data you are inserting.
  - Run db..explain("executionStats") on the query to find out 
    which of the indexes is being used.
  - Remove all other indexes as they will affect your inserts performance.
  - Run your full query and see how it performs using the new index.

Comment: make sense, nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java api, here is the reference for the correct usage:

http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html?_ga=1.119232521.1817714352.1461227368#createIndex-org.bson.conversions.Bson-

http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/model/IndexOptions.html

Basically you need to provide the background option correctly using api's IndexOptions.

Comment: i am using 3.2.1, it does not allow me, see my edit in question, do i need to change anything else

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Data MongoDB then you can use the builder methods on the Index() class to set the background property:

```
new Index(CREATED_DATE_FIELD_NAME, Sort.Direction.DESC).background();
```